# Formula for absolute value which is defined for abs(0)

Tags: absolute-value

Is there an equation `f(x)` for absolute value, that is defined for every defined value of x, without using separate equation for different ranges.

It should be defined without using a conditional check.

Comment: Why not just use the piecewise definition of $|x|$ ?

Comment: @learner Apparantly, the OP does not like distincting the cases.

Comment: @Bye_World Sorry, updated the equation. I was thinking of a way to +1 and -1 alternately for a series and had `abs(x)/x` in my mind when I typed the question. I have updated the question with the actual equation, that I intended to write.

Comment: @Peter You are right, I have removed the equation all together.

Comment: I think the version $\sqrt{x^2}$ is the best possible way to define $|x|$ without distincting the cases, since |x| is only continous at $x_0=0$, but not differentiable.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that was the equation I had in mind. I couldn't recollect it once I started writing the question. I only remembered that it was not defined for zero.

Comment: @JoyceBabu That was unlucky. The first hits are confusing and misleading.

Comment: @JoyceBabu Time to "clean" the site. Let us delete unnecessary comments now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the convention that $\sqrt{x}$ is always non-negative, we have $$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

You can also use $$|x|=x\cdot sign(x)$$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

One equation for the absolute value functions is:

$$
f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0},
$$

given by

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
x&\text { if }x\geq 0\\
-x&\text { if }x< 0
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}.
$$

So, for instance, $f(5)=5$ since $5\geq 0$, while $f(-4.7)=-(-4.7)=4.7$, since $-4.7<0$.

Answer (score 1):

An absolute value can be written as: $$|x|=
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
x&\text { if }x\geq 0\\
-x&\text { if }x< 0
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}$$

OR

$$|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$$ = The above notation describes the principal root of $x^2$ (Positive)